# How to compose a container from a Image and layer in Docker 1.10

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Two questions. Thanks in advance.

1. In V 1.10, how to get new layer ID after creating a new container
   from a image? In previous version, the layer ID is the same as
   container ID which is returned from RestAPI "POST
   /containers/create"? Looks like the new layer ID is saved in the
   last item in manifest.json, but this assumption is not safe.
2. How to restore a container from an Image and above layer.tar?
   RestAPI "PUT /containers/(id or name)/archive" may only handles a normal tar          file instead of lay.tar, and it can't handle the deleted files in the new container.

Comment: Would `docker commit' (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) - or the API equivalent https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#create-a-new-image-from-a-container-s-changes be what you're looking for?

Comment: Those two commands don't help. I want to get the new layer ID after creating a new container, and to restore a container from its image and a layer.tar